# SQLite updating row

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am developing a mobile application on cordova with a SQLite database.

The application receives data from an external source via JSONP and writes data to the database.

I need to use the sql query to determine if there is an entry in the table with a specific id, rewriting the row if there is and adding a new one if there is not.

At the moment, the data writing function looks like this:

```
    addNews: function (id, title, date, content) {
    databaseHandler.db.transaction(
        function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql(
                "insert into news(id, title, date, content) values(?, ?, ?, ?)",
                [id, title, date, content],
                function (tx, results) { },
                function (tx, error) {
                    console.log("add news error: " + error.message);
                }
            );
        },
        function (error) {
        },
        function () {
        }
    );
}

var url = "http://cp35240-wordpress.tw1.ru/wp-content/plugins/plugin/news.js";
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('src', url);
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

function news(data) {
    var id = data.id;
    var title = data.title;
    var date = data.date;
    var content = data.content;  
    newsHandler.addNews(id, title, date, content);   
}
```

Comment: please describe the problem you are encountering / what's not working the way you expect / what error is occurring / etc.

Comment: @landru27 Сurrently the data in the table is not updated, but duplicated. ibb.co/c7ghTV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make useof `INSERT OR REPLACE`

Syntax

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO TABLE (column_list) 
VALUES (value_list);
```

So here you can use

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO news(id, title, date, content) values(?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Or you can use `UPSERT`

```
INSERT INTO news(id, title, date, content) 
values(?, ?, ?, ?)
ON CONFLICT(Id) DO UPDATE 
    SET tile=?
```

Further [Read](https://sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html)

Comment: It isn't works. Rows continue to be duplicated... https://ibb.co/c7ghTV

Comment: @JS588787 Please check now with the upsert way i have updated the answer

Comment: I got an error: number of '?'s in statement string does not match argument count